# How to add image to a sectioned List View

Tags: android, listview

I have a segmented listview, each cell contains some text and an Image, as shown below.

[image]

I am using this code to populate the fields,

```
 adapter.addSection((keys.get(i)), new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), security, R.layout.list_complexblue, new String[] { ITEM_TITLE, ITEM_CAPTION, ITEM_DATE, VISIBLE_DATE, LINK, IMAGE }, new int[] { R.id.list_complex_title, R.id.list_complex_caption, R.id.list_complex_pubDate, R.id.list_visible_pubDate, R.id.list_complex_link, R.id.list_complex_image }));
```

R.id.list_complex_image: This is the id for image

Everything is working perfectly, but how can i put image to imageview using this adapter. 
Please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking for here. Are you asking for instructions on how to use SimpleAdapter or your sectioned adapter? In the latter case, knowing how you've implemented the sectioned adapter would help. Also, is R.id.list_complex_image the id for the image, or the ImageView you want it in?

Comment: R.id.list_complex_image this is the id of imageview, i have implmented the sectioned listview, but dont know how to proceed from here. What i want is the image in each row of listview....thanks

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. I think you might have to add some extra context, so that it is easier to answer.

Comment: Ok...i solved it now, just use refrence in the map.

Comment: That is great! Add your solution, and award yourself the answer, so that others may learn from you! :)